# Google Maps Flutter cannot tap on map toolbar on android device, but I can tap on the map toolbar on an emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I'm using google_maps_flutter from pub.dev for my flutter application.

I'm having an issue where when I click a marker, the map toolbar slides in from the right hand corner of the screen as it should, but I cannot tap on the map toolbar buttons. The toolbar just slides back out of view when I tap it. I also am not able to tap on the zoom in and zoom out buttons. I am able to tap on the compass button just in case that matters.

The weird thing is that I only have this problem when I'm using a real device. If I use an emulator, I am able to tap on the map toolbar buttons which brings me to Google Maps and the zoom in and zoom out buttons.

I'm not sure what is going on and googling has led me nowhere.

I have already tried the following,

Remove the Google Map widget from a Stack,

I've tried to add the gestureRecognizers like this,

```
gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognize>> [
    new Factory <OneSequenceGestureRecognizer> (
        () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
    ),
].toSet()
```

If you don't mind pointing me in the right direction to solve this issue, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this gestures

```
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
                        ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => PanGestureRecognizer()))
                        ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
                        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => TapGestureRecognizer()))
                        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
```

Comment: Hey Kishan, I used the gestureRecognizers that you suggested but unfortunately I am still unable to tap the mapToolbar or the zoomControls. Thanks though!